# Complexity of Lebesgue measurable spaces

Tags: measure-theory, statistics, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, machine-learning

Consider a discrete finite set $\Omega=X\times Y \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ for finite $m,n$. Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ be the measure space. ($\Sigma$ is the power set and $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite measure.)

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be the set of all measurable functions on the above measure space. Clearly $|\mathcal{X}|$ (cardinality or size of $\mathcal{X}$) is **exponential** in $|\Omega|$.

Question 1: Can we come up with a dense subset of $\mathcal{X}$ such that we can get better complexity in the dimensions? I mean do we have something of *VC-dimension* or *Covering number* sorts for $\mathcal{X}$ that we can rely on which is way better than directly using $|\mathcal{X}|$?

Or let's consider a subset of $\mathcal{X}$. That is, consider the lebesgue measurable space $L_p(\mu)\subseteq \mathcal{X}$ for $p\geq 1$.

Question 2: Is there a *VC-dimension* or *Covering number* sorts for $L_p(\mu)$ spaces in literature?

I spent last couple of hours (only to end up writing this post at 3am!) researching on this. All I could see were *unsatisfactory*. For example:

From paper titled "The Learning Rates of Regularized Regression Based on
Reproducing Kernel Banach Spaces": (I don't know how big $s$ would be for $L_p(\mu)$  spaces!)

[image]

Comment: Since $\Omega$ is finite, the measure $\mu$ is finite as well. Hence the $L^p$-Norm consists of  a sum with finitely many summands, so every function is in $L^p$. On the other hand the dimension of $\mathcal{X}=\{f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\}$ is finite as well. A basis is given by the function $f_y(x):=\delta_{xy}$. That means the dimension is $|\Omega|$.

Comment: @humanStampedist 
Is $\mathcal{X}=\{f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\}$ the set of all measurable functions? If so, we have as many $f$'s as $|\Sigma|=2^{|\Omega|}$ right?
If otherwise, how can we say that the basis $\delta_{xy}$ generates all measurable function class $\mathcal{X}$?
Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Since $\Sigma$ is the power set of $\Omega$, every function is measurable.

Comment: @humanStampedist Yeah, I should've been more clearer. I actually need this constructed new space (like the basis you mentioned) of measurable functions to be decomposable. I wrote a new question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4444086/example-of-a-decomposable-measure-space-with-finite-size-that-isnt-exponential
Please take a look if you can!